# Code runs fine through a debugger but crashes on execution

Tags: c++, debugging

Can someone point out or give a hint on what's going on? Why is it when I run the code line-by-line using the built-in debugger, it gives the correct `returnAry`, but crashes when I try to execute the program?

No debugger:
[image]

With debugger:
[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fraction.h"
#include "fractionUtilities.h"
using namespace std;

int* getUncommon(Fraction*, int);

int main() {
    Fraction testAry[] = { 1201, 6266, 35, 77 };
    int size = 4;
    int* result;
    result = getUncommon(testAry, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < result[0] + 1; i++) {
        cout << result[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int* getUncommon(Fraction* ary, int size) {
    int* returnAry = 0;
    int tmp;
    int** digitInfoAry = new int*[size];
    int i, j;
    int sizeAry = 10;
    int digitAry[10]{ 0 };
    int uncommonDigitCount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeAry; i++) {
        *(digitInfoAry + i) = new int[sizeAry] {0};
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tmp = (ary + i)->getNum() < 0 ? -(ary + i)->getNum() : (ary + i)->getNum();

        do {
            *(*(digitInfoAry + i) + tmp % 10) = 1;
            tmp /= 10;
        } while (tmp != 0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizeAry; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            digitAry[i] += *(*(digitInfoAry + j) + i);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizeAry; i++) {
        if (digitAry[i] == 1) {
            uncommonDigitCount++;
        }
    }

    returnAry = new int[uncommonDigitCount + 1];
    *returnAry = uncommonDigitCount;

    if (uncommonDigitCount != 0) {
        for (i = 0, j = 1; i < sizeAry; i += 2) {
            if (digitAry[i] % 2 == 1) {
                returnAry[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }

        for (i = 1; i < sizeAry; i += 2) {
            if (digitAry[i] % 2 == 1) {
                returnAry[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    return returnAry;
}
```

Thank you ahead of time for your help, I really cannot figure out what is going on, it's driving me insane!

Comment: Well ... undefined behavior in `*(digitInfoAry + i) = new int[sizeAry] {0};` `digitInfoAry` is allocated with `size == 4`, but you access `sizeAray == 10` elements. Also: What's wrong with `digitInfoAry[i] = `, which makes this much more readable?

Comment: Problems like yours are usually caused by out-of-bounds writes. In Debugging the memory regions before and past an array are usually accessible (so that memory debugging tools can place canary values there to see if they get clobbered). You're using C++ so the real question is: Why are you not using `std::vector`s instead of manually managing storage?

Comment: You also allocate two arrays and ten integers dynamically, but leak all that memory.

Comment: possibly the last two loops `j` goes out of bounds; to test this you could put before `returnAry[j] = i;` the code `if ( j >= uncommonDigitCount + 1 ) std::cerr << "FAIL\n";` or something

Comment: This code is pretty confusing... ary, digitary, digitinfoary, size, sizeary.. what size is what?  It should be obvious from variable names without having to mentally track .  This is why we advise to not use raw pointers and `new` .

Comment: Why it works in debugger and not when run normally: It didn't work in debugger. You got unlucky and the failure did not crash the program, lulling you into a false sense of security. Debuggers do change execution in small ways, but they are generally the smallest possible ways. Code built in debug mode is radically different from code in release mode and while they do the same thing, or as close as possible, they do not do the same things the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to fix this:

```
int** digitInfoAry = new int*[size];
...
for (i = 0; i < sizeAry; i++) {
    *(digitInfoAry + i) = new int[sizeAry] {0};
}
```

Then loop runs from `0` to `sizeAry` indices goes beyond allocated memory.